# Is architecture in our scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

I can see one side of Architecture being in our scope, but the art side not being in our scope. There will likely be some combining of the two.

I don't know enough about the day to day activities or interests of architects to know if they will be drawn here though.

Comment: Architectural Engineering is a discipline within the many branches of engineering.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the  architecture questions are about engineering, structural concerns, foundations, then yes. Questions about material and their properties will depend on the question. Questions about:

- insulation - maybe
- orientation for best natural lighting - no
- is Oregon pine better than beech or oak - unlikely
- thermal properties of different types of cladding - maybe
- construction methods - maybe
- acoustics - the question would have to be very specific
- internal lighting - unlikely
- the strength & properties of specific mixes of concrete - yes
- soundproofing - maybe
- electromagnetic & radiation shielding - yes
- single glazing compared to double or triple glazing - unlikely

Comment: I would welcome questions on all the above topics as real engineering. Also architects have expertise in project management, and the use of built environments, which could be great answers. However, I don't know answers for most of the listed topics myself, and I think those Fred marks as unlikely are unlikely to be asked here.

Comment: I think in the spirit of this answer, let's worry more about individual questions and whether they draw on engineering knowledge or aesthetic knowledge, rather than worrying about what discipline they come from. There are architects who work at all different spots along this spectrum.